# Activity switch and Async Android

Tags: android-layout, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-view, background-process

I have 2 activities: `MainActivity` which is associated with `main.xml` layout (app "Home" screen) and `AboutActivity` which is associated with `about.xml` layout (app "About" screen).

While in `AboutActivity`, an `Async` task within `MainActivity` still tries to access `main.xml`. My app to stop working as a result.

Is there any way I can?

- "pause" the `Async` task within `MainActivity` and "resume" them when
  the user switches back from `AboutActivity`
- or still access `main.xml` in the background while in `AboutActivity`

*Additional information:*
`MainActivity` is the launch activity. `AboutActivity extends MainActivity`. Users can go to "About" screen/ switch to `AboutActivity` using the option menu.

The `Async` task within `MainActivity` put the user's current location into a textview. `about.xml` only contains static text. `AboutActivity` does nothing but show `about.xml`.

AboutActivity:

```
public class AboutActivity extends MainActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.about);

    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
            PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   

        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
            placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
        }

        /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            //make asynctask wait for debugger
            //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.d(DEBUG,e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
                TextView curLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurrentLocation);
                curLoc.setText(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask not pause  so we can store the data temporary when task complete and while start background activity than show data on textView.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. It was a partly a variable scope problem and partly due the fact that I cannot use `findViewById()` there, it always return null

`curLoc` is null in onPostExecute in the AsyncTask.

I removed the following:

```
TextView curLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurrentLocation);
```

and declared curLoc as a attribute of the class MainActivity

```
private TextView curLoc;
```

and also put in onCreate()

```
curLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurrentLocation);
```